# Generic super class in java

Tags: java, class, generics, extends

Is it possible to create something like this in java

```
public abstract class GenericView<LAYOUTTYPE extends AbstractLayout> extends LAYOUTTYPE
```

so that

```
public class MyView extends GenericView<HorizontalLayout>
```

extends `GenericView` and `HorizontalLayout` and

```
public class MyView2 extends GenericView<VerticalLayout>
```

extends `GenericView` and `VerticalLayout`?

Comment: That would be pretty neat in some cases but I doubt it's possible.

Comment: Even if this was possible it is useless.

Comment: @talex Oh, I don't know - it could be like a weak form of multiple inheritance which can at times come in handy. It brings dangers though.

Comment: @blalasaadri How you expect it to work. Since there are no compile time information about methods or fields in `LAYOUTTYPE` it doesn't add anything to interface.

Comment: @talex Actually there is some compiletime information: it extends `AbstractLayout`. I do see many problems with it nevertheless - functions that are defined more than once for example and let's not ignore Type Erasure - but I can also see why someone may want to use something like this at times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer - no. The type you `extends` must be an actual type, not a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to accomplish multiple inheritance, inheriting from both a `View` and a `Layout`. This is not possible in Java. You can accomplish something similar with composition. If your `GenericView` must also provide the functionality given by `AbstractLayout`, then you can accomplish it like this:

```
public interface Layout {
    // Layout functions
    public void doLayout();
}

public class GenericView<T extends AbstractLayout> implements Layout {
    private final T delegateLayout;

    // Construct with a Layout
    public GenericView(T delegateLayout) {
        this.delegateLayout = delegateLayout;
    }

    // Delegate Layout functions (Eclipse/IntelliJ can generate these for you):
    public void doLayout() {
        this.delegateLayout.doLayout();
    }

    // Other GenericView methods
}

public class VerticalLayout extends AbstractLayout {
    public void doLayout() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

After this, you can actually do this:

```
new GenericView<VerticalLayout> (new VerticalLayout());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is not possible in Java. The main reason I can think of is the problem with Type Erasure - once that class is compiled it will no longer know what `LAYOUTTYPE` is.

What I think you're trying to achieve is a sort of multiple inheritance - so you can combine features from `LAYOUTTYPE` with those of `GenericView`. Multiple inheritance is - as you probably know - not possible in Java. However you can use multiple interfaces which for many cases will be sufficient. If you're using Java 8 you can even have `default` implementations for many functions in those interfaces (though only if it makes sense of course).