# Parametrizing a Java class to take arbitrary many interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface in Java that has lots of parameters specific for a certain type of tests. Then I have a utility class with functions that can be reused for lots of different projects, the only thing I want to change are the parameters used in the utility functions.

The solution im trying is to make the test utility class parameterized on the type of interfaces I want it to implement. I would like to be able to send one or more interfaces to the class. Like shown below:

```
public class TestsetA extends TestUtilityFunctions<ParametersA,...> {}

public class TestUtilityFunctions<T...> implements T... {}
```

However this is giving me the error: `Can not refer to type parameter T as supertype.`

How can I implement this with Java generics?

UPDATE:
The usecase im trying to solve is the following:

```
public abstract class TestUtilityFunctions<T implements CommonProperties> {

   protected void initRestAssured() {
      RestAssured.port = T.PORT;
      RestAssured.basePath = T.BASE_URL;
}}

public class MyATests extends TestUtilityFunctions<ParametersForA> {

}

public class MyBTests extends TestUtilityFunctions<ParametersForB> {

}
```

Comment: You can't (generics can't add methods to a class, they can only change what type they work on). Explain your use case with a litte example in source of how / why and people may be able to find a working idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400049/generic-super-class-in-java

Comment: I have updated with a better example showing my intent better i hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to pass in an instance

```
public abstract class TestUtilityFunctions<T implements CommonProperties> {
    private final T props;
    protected TestUtilityFunctions(T props) {
        this.props = props;
    }
    protected void initRestAssured() {
        // are PORT and BASE_URL static? 
        // if no, they shouldn't be capitals (use getPort() and getBaseUrl())
        // if yes, this is bad design
        RestAssured.port = props.PORT;
        RestAssured.basePath = props.BASE_URL;
    }
}
```